# Mock and get return value from json.dump() in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have an example test snippet:

```
import unittest
import json

from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock, mock_open

class TestDataParser(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):

        with open('text_file.txt', 'w') as file:
           json.dump({'test':'dump'}, file)
```

I am not sure how I would be able to mock the `dump` call and get the value that is inputted as the first parameter. I was trying something similar to

```
with patch('json.dump', MagicMock()) as m:
   with open('text_file.txt', 'w') as file:
        json.dump({'test':'dump'}, file)
```

and calling `m.return_value` to get the value that was meant to be dumped. However, this doesn't seem to be working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to mock, `json.dumps`, `open`, or both?

Comment: My goal was to mock `json.dump` and get whatever was "dumped"

Comment: But, where do you'll get this? In test, or in file that you're writing?